# SQL that produces result table of 3 columns:

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe

From a table containing (among others) columns `branch` and `rqst_type`, I want a result table  of 3 columns: `branch`, `rqst_type` and `sum`.

Only the branches that have `rqst_types` in (200, 201, 202) should be included and in `sum` the number of rows per branch of 200, 201 and 202 respectively. Also the select must be between dates (using column `send_date` for this).

Anyone have an idea how to produce this?

```
 BRANCH ! MSG_TYPE !        SUM
--------+----------+---------------
 BAEE   ! 200      !            134
 BAEE   ! 202      !            221
 BALV   ! 200      !            102
 BALV   ! 202      !            293
 BLTL   ! 200      !             66
 BLTL   ! 202      !            210
 CLUT   ! 202      !         464710
 CURT   ! 202      !         226760
 DBFX   ! 200      !            519
 DBFX   ! 201      !              8    
 DBFX   ! 202      !          74811
 DBFX   ! 203      !            424
```

Comment: Please post sample data and expected result.

Comment: how can I format the comment? never mind, I put in in the question

Comment: Edit the question and type in your expected data.

Comment: Don't make comments - edit your post :)

Comment: You want `COUNT()`, not `SUM()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` to compute for the number of rows and add a `WHERE` clause to filter the data:

```
SELECT
    BRANCH,
    MSG_TYPE,
    COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable
WHERE
    MSG_TYPE IN (200, 201, 202)
    AND send_date BETWEEN <from_date> AND <end_date>
GROUP BY
    BRANCH, MSG_TYPE
```